# Mongodb saying pretty() is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to pull info from a Mongodb data and keep getting this error:

[image]

Here is the section of code cause the issue:

[image]

Comment: Er.. what `.pretty()` is supposed to do? It's not part of NodeJs or ExpessJS afaik

Comment: its supposed to format the output on the webpage

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include all relevant details and be formatted correctly, in particular, please post code and errors as text (and not as image).

Answer (score 2):

The pretty function is not a function in the res object, its part of the mongoDB object: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.pretty/

You should add the .pretty() after the .find(), and not to the response.

It would help to paste here the code and not just a photo of it so we could play with it and help a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
collection.find({key:value}).pretty().toArray()...
```

You need to pass `pretty()` after the `find()` not with `res.send(db).preety()`